# Webpack && stylus-loader incorrectly resolve url paths

Tags: webpack, stylus

Let's say I have

`home.styl
menu/
  menu.styl
  image.svg`

`home.styl` is required from an entry point or JS.

Then:

`home.styl` imports `menu/menu.styl`
`menu/menu.styl` has `url(image.svg)`.

**The problem is that `image.svg` is not found.**

It exists in the same folder as `menu.styl`, but is not resolved.

The loaders are:

`loaders: [{
  test:   /\.styl$/,
  loader: 'style!css!stylus'
}, {
  test:   /\.(png|jpg|svg|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
  loader: 'file?name=[path][name].[ext]'
}]`

Below are my ideas why that fails.
Hope to get an answer how to fix that.

===========

If `url(image.svg)` is required from `menu.styl`, it should be looked up in the folder with `menu.styl`. That's because the path is relative by default.

But what's going on is the following:

1. Stylus-loader processes all `styl`, joins imports into one big `css`
2. CSS-loader gets `css` with the root context, namely the directory of `home.styl`
3. Then CSS-loader resolved all `url(...)` paths relative to that upper context.

So the image is searched in the folder of `home.styl` instead of `menu.styl`.

How to fix that?

P.S. The example project repo is at https://github.com/iliakan/stylus-path-problem

Comment: P.S. SASS is also broken this way. LESS is ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use `stylus-loader`'s `resolve url` option, which will replace the `url()` function inside your `.styl` files with a custom resolver.

```
{
  test:   /\.styl$/,
  loader: 'style!css!stylus?resolve url'
}
```

See [the corresponding code](https://github.com/shama/stylus-loader/blob/master/index.js#L72). Pretty cool solution.

Comment: Yeah, right, just digged that out myself.
LESS has that by enabled by default. Stylus, SASS do not, but can be enabled for stylus exactly the way you say. Did not dig SASS, guess doable also.

Comment: This isn't working for me I have... `"raw!stylus-loader?resolve url"` but when I look it is still trying to use http.

Comment: For me it doesn't work even with resolve url option when css-loader?modules is NOT set. I have two configs for *modules.styl and *.styl

see https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/282