# Webpack with Stylus-loader and Url-Loader not loading images

Tags: webpack, stylus, urlloader

I have the following structure

```
...
  login
    login.styles.styl
    background.png
```

In Webpack

```
...
{
  test: /\.styl$/,
  loader: "style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader"
},
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?.*)?$/,
  loader: 'url?limit=900000'
}
...
```

In login.styles.styl I have tried all these but none work...

```
background: url(./background.png)
background: url('./background.png')
background: './background.png'
```

I have also tried this per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450953/webpack-stylus-loader-incorrectly-resolve-url-paths) but it doesn't work...

```
{
  test:   /\.styl$/,
  loader: 'style!css!stylus?resolve url'
}
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

**Update**

I forgot since this is an ng2 App it isn't using the same generic loader...

```
styles: [require('!raw!stylus!./login.styles.styl')],
```

I tried both

```
styles: [require('!raw!css!stylus!./login.styles.styl')],
styles: [require('!to-string!css!stylus!./login.styles.styl')],
```

But neither seem to work

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this ended up working...

```
    {
      test: /\.styl$/,
      loaders: ["to-string", "css", "stylus"]
    },
```